# download a file from a website which requires authetication using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

I am trying to download a CSV file from a website using python 2.7. I already found some posting about how to retrieve files.

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/07/python-101-how-to-download-a-file/

[How do I download a file over HTTP using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python)

However, the site that I am trying to access requires authentication: id and password. I was wondering if anyone out there might share an example of how to download a file with authentication barrier.

Comment: What *kind* of authentication barrier? Cookie-based (HTML form login), or HTTP based (browser pops up a login prompt as a modal dialog)?

Comment: [Here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/authentication.shtml) is a tutorial for http based authentication with python/urllib2. This wont work if the authentication is cookie based.

Comment: Please check it out by the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496655/download-a-file-providing-username-and-password-using-python), in which there is an example of using request module.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module, and its documentation.