# How to filter filenames with extension on API call?

Tags: python, api, confluence

I was working on the python confluence API for downloading attachment from confluence page, I need to download only files with `.mpp` extension. Tried with `glob` and direct parameters but didnt work.

Here is my code:

```
file_name = glob.glob("*.mpp")
attachments_container = confluence.get_attachments_from_content(page_id=33110, start=0, limit=1,filename=file_name)
print(attachments_container)
attachments = attachments_container['results']
for attachment in attachments:
    fname = attachment['title']
    download_link = confluence.url + attachment['_links']['download']
    r = requests.get(download_link, auth = HTTPBasicAuth(confluence.username,confluence.password))
    if r.status_code == 200:
        if not os.path.exists('phoenix'):
            os.makedirs('phoenix')
        fname = ".\\phoenix\\" +fname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) operates on your *local* folder. So you can't use that as a filter for `get_attachments_from_content()`. Also, don't specify a `limit` of since that gets you just one/the first attachment. Specify a high limit or whatever default will include all of them. (You may have to paginate results.)

However, you can exclude the files you don't want by checking the `title` of each attachment before you download it, which you have as `fname = attachment['title']`.

```py
attachments_container = confluence.get_attachments_from_content(page_id=33110, limit=1000)
attachments = attachments_container['results']
for attachment in attachments:
    fname = attachment['title']
    if not fname.lower().endswith('.mpp'):
        # skip file if it's not got that extension
        continue
    download_link = ...
    # rest of your code here
```

Also, your code looks like a [copy-paste from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60039639/1431750) but you've changed the actual "downloading" part of it. So if your next StackOverflow question is going to be "how to download a file from confluence", use that answer's code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , I am using limit attribute coz i only want the latest (last updated) attachment from the confluence page, does it work that way?

Comment: I don't think that's how the `limit` parameter works. `limit` _usually_ means the number of results you want. So `start=0` and `limit=10` will give you 10 items (0-9). You'll need to verify that from the docs. Also, if you want to check if you've already downloaded the attachment, check with [`os.path.exists(".\\phoenix\\" +fname)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) and don't download if it does exist. If it's only the last attachment uploaded, what happens if two '.mpp' files are uploaded after your script last runs? You'll end up missing one of them.

Comment: Yes Sir , you are correct , i think the confluence sorting the attachment list based on the updated time , may be thats the limit =1 will fetch the last updated one. i am planning for polling using this python script , and only having one MPP file.